# Http request in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am new to Ionic framework & going to develop an app which utilises rest api from my server. In each API I have to pass a token in http header. If this token is valid then I return response & inflate the listview. If token is not valid then I have to hit another API to generate token & again hit first API to fetch data.

My problem is second case. When token is invalid, it is generate successfully & then calling first API is also successful but this time listview is not inflated.
Please help.

home.ts

```
loadPeople(){
this.dataService.load()
 .then(data => {
   this.mylist = data;
  });
}
```

data-provider.ts

```
load() {
 if (this.data) {
 return Promise.resolve(this.data);
}

return new Promise(resolve => {
let headers = new Headers({ 'token': this.token });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.get('myurl1', options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    if(data.message === 'TOKEN_NOTVALID'){
       this.generateToken();
    }else{
        this.data = data.result;
      resolve(this.data);
    }
  });
 });
 }
```

generateAccessToken(){

```
 var creds = "param1=xxx&param2=zzz";
 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

 this.http.post('myUrlHere', creds, {
   headers: headers
   })
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(
     data => {
     this.token = data.token;
     this.load();
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when token is invalid , the `Promise` is never resolved. Only the second call to `load` function `Promise` is resolved. So you need to resolve the `Promise` when token is not valid. Just because the name of the function is `resolve` in the `Promise`, doesnt mean that the second call to load function will resolve the first call to load function.

You can return the `data` promise in  `generateAccessToken` then resolve the promise with data returned.

```
load() {
 if (this.data) {
 return Promise.resolve(this.data);
}

return new Promise(resolve => {
let headers = new Headers({ 'token': this.token });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.get('myurl1', options)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    if(data.message === 'TOKEN_NOTVALID'){
       this.generateToken().then(data => { resole(data) } );
    }else{
        this.data = data.result;
      resolve(this.data);
    }
  });
 });
 }

generateAccessToken(){

 var creds = "param1=xxx&param2=zzz";
 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

 return this.http.post('myUrlHere', creds, {
   headers: headers
   })
   .map(res => res.json())
   .toPromise()
   .then(
     data => {
     this.token = data.token;
     return this.load();
     });
 }
```

You will have to import `toPromise`

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it is giving 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

error.